# Data binding into textblock from sqlite database on windows store app

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml

I'm trying to bind my data from sqlite.net database into textblock. I've searched a lot about it, but I still have a few problems:
1) anoying exception occurs where in the Additional Information is: "Constraint" and nothing else. The problem is also that it doesn't appear every time I run the app.
2) I cannot see my Binding data into the textblock.

I've composed me code according to this example: [Windows Store App writing sqlite query into the listview's textblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512893/windows-store-app-writing-sqlite-query-into-the-listviews-textblocks)

I've tried also this [select data from sqlite database and binding values to listbox item in windows phone 8 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956476/select-data-from-sqlite-database-and-binding-values-to-listbox-item-in-windows-p)
but none of this solving my problem.

Here is my XAML code:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/rankingTlo.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Text="Pytanie" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="20" Margin="-83,71,0,0" Foreground="#FF353535" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFB41019" Margin="17,59,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="33" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="z" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF353535" Margin="56,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="14" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF353535" Margin="109,59,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="33" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Text="poziom" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Margin="-88,96,0,0" Foreground="#FF353535" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Text="licealista" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Margin="47,96,0,0" Foreground="#FFB41019" FontWeight="Bold"/>

    <ListView Name="listView1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Width="Auto" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding tresc_pytania}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="24"/>                   
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

class pytania
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int id_pytania { get; set; }
    public string tresc_pytania { get; set; }
    public int poziom_trudnosci { get; set; }        
    public string odpowiedz1 { get; set; }
    public string odpowiedz2 { get; set; }
    public string odpowiedz3 { get; set; }
    public string odpowiedz4 { get; set; }
    public int dobra_odpowiedz { get; set; }

}

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "baza.ext");

        using (var dbConn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            var query = dbConn.Table<pytania>();
            listView1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Hope to hear from you some piece of advice.
Best regards,
Tomas

Comment: have you looked at your variable **query**? anything in it?

Comment: problem solved! Everything was about wrong path to database. Now I'd like to read only one row from database not just the hole column, any idea how to do it?

Comment: If you want to filter your results (e.g just one column) add where clause to your query. e.g. "var item = dbConn.Query<pytania>("SELECT * FROM pytania WHERE id_pytania = " + some_id_pytania);